# Fit a long table in multiple horizontal pages

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

I would like to have your assistance to fit a long table into multiple horizontal pages. I really appreciate your time and help. Because of the word limits, I could not post the whole of my table on here. 
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
%\centering
\caption{Table 3 (a). Courier....}
\label{my-label}
\scriptsize

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Variables}}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Unit}}}                                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Min/ Max or \\ Values*\end{tabular}}}}      & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Percentages or Distribution*}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         \\ \cline{4-7} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                                                              & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{US (n1 = n11+ n12 = 549)}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{VN ( n2 = n21+ n22 = 415)}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \\ \hline
    Experience: Sending package/ purchase online.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & NA                                                                                        & 1/2                                                                                                                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{38.25/ 61.75}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{23.86/ 76.14}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     \\ \hline
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}I, III: Sending package\\ II, IV: Purchase online\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           &                                                                                           &                                                                                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}I.\\ (n11 = 210)\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}II.\\ (n12 = 339)\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}III.\\ (n21 = 99)\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}IV.\\ (n22 = 316)\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}What have you sent to someone else/ you bought (multiple\\ choices): Dry cleaning, fast foods, lunch, dinner, birthday \\ \\ \\ cake, etc (immediate delivery)\textasciicircum 1/ Groceries\textasciicircum 2/ Beverage, dry \\ foods\textasciicircum 3/ Personal health, medicine\textasciicircum 4/ Apparel\textasciicircum 5/ Books,\\ \\  \\ Music, Videos\textasciicircum 6/ Consumer electronics\textasciicircum 7/ Others\textasciicircum 8.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                         \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(I, III, IV) 1/3;\\ (II) 1/5\end{tabular}                                               & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}74.90/ 13.30/\\ 11.80\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}6.20\textasciicircum 1/ 71.00\textasciicircum 2/ \\ 1.00\textasciicircum 3/ 0.50\textasciicircum 4/ \\ 21.40\textasciicircum 5\end{tabular}                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}41.40/ 34.30/ \\ 24.20\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3.20/ 75.00/ \\ \\ 21.80\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \hline                                                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}-\textasciicircum 1/ 3.30\textasciicircum 2/ \\ -\textasciicircum 3/ -\textasciicircum 4/\\ 21.00\textasciicircum 5/\\ 44.80\textasciicircum 6/ \\ 31.00\textasciicircum 7/ -\textasciicircum 8\end{tabular}                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}4.00\textasciicircum 1/ \\ 3.00\textasciicircum 2/ \\ 37.50\textasciicircum 3/ \\ 50.50\textasciicircum 4/ \\ 3.00\textasciicircum 5/ \\ 2.00\textasciicircum 6\end{tabular}                                                        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}61.40\textasciicircum 1/ 7.90\textasciicircum 2/\\ 3.20\textasciicircum 3/ 0.90\textasciicircum 4/\\ 3.20\textasciicircum 5/ 0.30\textasciicircum 6/ \\ 22.80\textasciicircum 7/ 0.30\textasciicircum 8\end{tabular}      \\ \hline
    Time for deliver.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   & Hours                                                                                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(I) 0.75/23; \\ \\ \\ (II) 0.5/ 19; \\ (III) 0.5/12; \\ (IV) 0.33/ 18\end{tabular}            & 7.65/ 1.27                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & 4.25/ 2.01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             & 3.73/ 0.36                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     & 4.39/ 0.28                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
    Time for deliver.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   & Days                                                                                      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(I) 1/28; \\ \\ \\ \\ (II) 1/18; \\ (III) 1/14; \\ (IV) 1/30\end{tabular}                        & 3.22/ 0.09                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & 3.46/ 0.13                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             & 2.75/ 0.24                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     & 2.64/ 0.13                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
    Satisfaction with the delivery time: No/ Yes.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & NA                                                                                        & 0/1                                                                                                                & 5.90/94.10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & 9.00/ 91.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            & 13.10/ 86.90                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   & 13.00/ 87.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         \\ \hline
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Able to track and trace the item online: Yes, I could track via \\ carrier’s website (and/or app)/ Yes, I could track by calling \\ courier’s cellphone / No, I could not track it.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         & NA                                                                                        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(I, II) 1/2; \\ (III, IV) 1/3\end{tabular}                                              & 94.40/ -/ 5.60                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    & 91.90/ -/ 8.10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}33.30/ 31.30/ \\ 35.40\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}27.20/ 25.60/\\  47.20\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Satisfaction with electronic delivery notification: Yes, I was \\ satisfied with the service/ No, the service was not good/ No, \\ they did not provide the service.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & NA                                                                                        & 1/3                                                                                                                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}82.60/ 3.80/ \\ 13.60\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}84.30/ 4.80/\\ 11.00\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}61.60/ 10.10/ \\ 28.30\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}68.00/ 8.50/ \\ 23.40\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \hline
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Choose the pickup (I, III)/delivery (II, IV) time window: Yes, \\ I could, and I used that service/ Yes, I could, but I did not use\\  that service/ No, I could not. The carrier did not offer that \\ service.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            & NA                                                                                        & 1/3                                                                                                                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}19.50/ 36.60/ \\ 44.00\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}30.00/ 20.50/ \\ 49.50\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}41.40/ 17.20/ \\ 41.40\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}56.60/ 24.40/ \\ 19.00\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Carriers offer pickup at home (I, III)/ provide convenient\\ \\ drop-off location (II, IV): Yes, \\ \\ \\ but I have never used the \\ service\textasciicircum 1/ Yes, the service is excellent\textasciicircum 2/ Yes, the service is \\ good\textasciicircum 3/ No, the service is bad\textasciicircum 4/ I have no idea about the \\ service\textasciicircum 5.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      & NA                                                                                        & 1/5                                                                                                                &                                                                          \\ \hline
    Did you tip the delivery person: No/ Yes.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           & NA                                                                                        & 0/1                                                                                                                & 92.90/ 7.10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & 97.60/ 2.40                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            & -                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              & -                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\ \hline
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Number of times did: (I, II) you \\ use the service of the carrier \\ per year; (II, IV) you shop \\ \\ \\ in the same website/shop per year.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           & Numbers                                                                                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(I, II) 1/300; \\ (III) 1/ 550;\\ (IV) 1/500.\end{tabular}                              & 18.41/ 35.92                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      & 19.23/ 27.98                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           & 25.05/ 73.87                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   & 7.07/ 31.01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: sidewaystable is a one-page environment. You can can't put a multipage longtable in it.

Comment: you should use `lanscape` enviroment from `lscape` or `pdflscape`.

Comment: that's `landscape`  with a d

Answer (score 1):

i suspect that you like to achieve something like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

but i'm not sure. ass I mentioned in comment, use of `landscape` environment enables use `longtable` over more pages.

i must confess that i was lost in your table code. i try to clean up it, but probably in this effort introduce some errors in table content. i did the following:

- add packages `pdflcscape`, `makecell` and `siunitx`
- with `\makecell` macro i replace all your nested tables
- with `siunitx i tray to use for constructs as is`Others\textasciicircum 8`, where i didn't figured out, what this circle means. so left them as you use in your *mwe*, but afer numbers i replace them with for example`\SI{2.00}{\degree}`
- in table i add many missing ampersands ...

code can be further improved if the context of table is known (for example, instead of `l` tape would be better to use `p{...}` type of columns or even use `tabularx` and `ltablex` package ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{makecell,   % added
            multirow, longtable}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}    % added


\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\scriptsize
\makegapedcells

\begin{longtable}{|p{55mm}|l|l |l|l|l|l|}
    \caption{Table 3 (a). Courier   \dots}
    \label{my-label}                \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{=}{\thead{Variables}}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Unit}}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Min/ Max or \\ Values*}}
            &   \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\thead{Percentages or Distribution*}}       \\
    \cline{4-7}
    &   &   &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{US $(n1 = n11+ n12 = 549)$}}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{VN $(n2 = n21+ n22 = 415)$}}   \\
    \hline
\makecell[l]{Experience:\\ Sending package/purchase online.}
    &   NA
        &   1/2
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{38.25/ 61.75}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{23.86/ 76.14}                   \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
    \caption{Table 3 (a). Courier   \dots (cont.)}                              \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Variables}}
    &   \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Unit}}
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Min/ Max or \\ Values*}}
            &   \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\thead{Percentages or Distribution*}}       \\
    \cline{4-7}
    &   &   &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{US $(n1 = n11+ n12 = 549)$}}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{VN $(n2 = n21+ n22 = 415)$}}   \\
    \hline
\makecell[l]{Experience:\\ Sending package/purchase online.}
    &   NA
        &   1/2
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{38.25/ 61.75}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{23.86/ 76.14}                   \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \multicolumn{7}{r}{\textit{continuation on the next page}}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
I, III: Sending package\newline
II, IV: Purchase online
    &   &   &   \makecell[t]{I.\\ $(n11 = 210)$}
                &   \makecell[t]{II.\\ $(n12 = 339)$}
                    &   \makecell[t]{III.\\ (n21 = 99)}
                        &   \makecell[t]{IV.\\ (n22 = 316)}                    \\
    \hline
What have you sent to someone else/ you bought (multiple choices): Dry cleaning, fast foods, lunch, dinner, birthday cake, etc (immediate delivery)\textasciicircum 1/ Groceries\textasciicircum 2/ Beverage, dry foods\textasciicircum 3/ Personal health, medicine\textasciicircum 4/ Apparel\textasciicircum 5/ Books, Music, Videos\textasciicircum 6/ Consumer electronics\textasciicircum 7/ Others\textasciicircum 8.
    &   \makecell[t]{(I, III, IV) 1/3;\\ (II) 1/5}
        &   \makecell[t]{74.90/ 13.30/\\ 11.80}
            &   \makecell[t]{\SI{6.20}{\degree} 1/ \SI{71.00}{\degree} 2/ \\
                          \SI{1.00}{\degree} 3/ \SI{0.50}{\degree} 4/  \\
                          \SI{21.40}{\degree} 5}
                &   \makecell[t]{41.40/ 34.30/ \\ 24.20}
                    &   \makecell[t]{3.20/ 75.00/ \\[3ex]
                         21.80}
                        &                                                   \\
    \hline
    &   \makecell[t]{-\textasciicircum 1/ \SI{3.30}{\degree} 2/  \\
                  -\textasciicircum 3/ -\textasciicircum 4/     \\
                  \SI{21.00}{\degree} 5/                      \\
                  \SI{44.80}{\degree} 6/                      \\
                  \SI{31.00}{\degree} 7/ -\textasciicircum 8}
        &   \makecell[t]{\SI{4.00}{\degree} 1/   \\
                      \SI{3.00}{\degree} 2/   \\
                      \SI{37.50}{\degree} 3/  \\
                      \SI{50.50}{\degree} 4/  \\
                      \SI{3.00}{\degree} 5/   \\
                      \SI{2.00}{\degree} 6}
            &   \makecell[t]{\SI{61.40}{\degree} 1/ \SI{7.90}{\degree} 2/\\
                          \SI{3.20}{\degree} 3/ \SI{0.90}{\degree} 4/ \\
                          \SI{3.20}{\degree} 5/ \SI{0.30}{\degree} 6/ \\
                          \SI{22.80}{\degree} 7/ \SI{0.30}{\degree} 8}
                &   &   &                                                            \\
    \hline
Time for deliver.
    & Hours
        &   \makecell[t]{(I) 0.75/23; \\ \\ \\ (II) 0.5/ 19; \\
                      (III) 0.5/12; \\ (IV) 0.33/ 18}
            &   7.65/ 1.27
                &   4.25/ 2.01
                    &   3.73/ 0.36
                        &   4.39/ 0.28                                              \\
    \hline
Time for deliver.
    & Days
        &   \makecell[t]{1/28; \\ \\ \\ \\
                      (II) 1/18; \\
                      (III) 1/14; \\
                      (IV) 1/30}
            &   3.22/ 0.09
                &   3.46/ 0.13
                    &   2.75/ 0.24
                        &   2.64/ 0.13                                          \\
    \hline
Satisfaction with the delivery time: No/ Yes.
    &   NA
        &   0/1
            &   5.90/94.10
                &   9.00/ 91.00
                    &   13.10/ 86.90
                        & 13.00/ 87.00                                          \\
    \hline
Able to track and trace the item online: Yes, I could track via
carrier’s website (and/or app)/ Yes, I could track by calling
courier’s cellphone / No, I could not track it.
    & NA
        &   \makecell[t]{(I, II) 1/2; \\ (III, IV) 1/3}
            &   94.40/ -/ 5.60
                &   91.90/ -/ 8.10
                    &   \makecell[t]{33.30/ 31.30/ \\ 35.40}
                        &   \makecell[t]{27.20/ 25.60/\\  47.20}                   \\
    \hline
Satisfaction with electronic delivery notification: Yes, I was satisfied with the service/ No, the service was not good/ No, they did not provide the service.
    &   NA
        &   1/3
            &   \makecell[t]{82.60/ 3.80/ \\ 13.60}
                &   \makecell[t]{84.30/ 4.80/\\ 11.00}
                    &   \makecell[t]{61.60/ 10.10/ \\ 28.30}
                        &   \makecell[t]{68.00/ 8.50/ \\ 23.40}                \\
    \hline
Choose the pickup (I, III)/delivery (II, IV) time window: Yes,  I could, and I used that service/ Yes, I could, but I did not use  that service/ No, I could not. The carrier did not offer that service.
    & NA
        & 1/3
            &   \makecell[t]{19.50/ 36.60/ \\ 44.00}
                &   \makecell[t]{30.00/ 20.50/ \\ 49.50}
                    &   \makecell[t]{41.40/ 17.20/ \\ 41.40}
                        &   \makecell[t]{56.60/ 24.40/ \\ 19.00}               \\
    \hline
Carriers offer pickup at home (I, III)/ provide convenient drop-off location (II, IV): Yes,  but I have never used the service\textasciicircum 1/ Yes, the service is excellent\textasciicircum 2/ Yes, the service is good\textasciicircum 3/ No, the service is bad\textasciicircum 4/ I have no idea about the service\textasciicircum 5.
    &   NA
        &   1/5
            &   &   &   &                                                   \\
    \hline
Did you tip the delivery person: No/ Yes.
    &   NA
        &   0/1
            &   92.90/ 7.10
                &   97.60/ 2.40
                    & -
                        & -                                                 \\
    \hline
Number of times did: (I, II) you use the service of the carrier per year; (II, IV) you shop in the same website/shop per year.
    &   Numbers
        &   \makecell[t]{(I, II) 1/300; \\ (III) 1/ 550;\\ (IV) 1/500.}
            &   18.41/ 35.92
                &   19.23/ 27.98
                    &   25.05/ 73.87
                        &   7.07/ 31.01                                 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```